# g1 gc 'Other' take a long time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

G1 gc 'Other' takes a long time. What is the most possible cause and how to solve it?

[gc log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfOpc.png)

jvm params:

> -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10 -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -Xss512k -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=128M -Xloggc:/med/log/mall-product.gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

```
2021-11-04T12:36:18.118+0800: 96537.313: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 45088768 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    3923792 bytes,    3923792 total
- age   2:     281104 bytes,    4204896 total
- age   3:     311088 bytes,    4515984 total
- age   4:      74304 bytes,    4590288 total
- age   5:      91728 bytes,    4682016 total
- age   6:      66368 bytes,    4748384 total
- age   7:     111832 bytes,    4860216 total
- age   8:      82232 bytes,    4942448 total
- age   9:      53752 bytes,    4996200 total
- age  10:      47432 bytes,    5043632 total
- age  11:     115944 bytes,    5159576 total
- age  12:     134000 bytes,    5293576 total
- age  13:     478392 bytes,    5771968 total
- age  14:     378696 bytes,    6150664 total
- age  15:     595856 bytes,    6746520 total
, 0.0161776 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 12.3 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 96537314.0, Avg: 96537314.0, Max: 96537314.1, Diff: 0.1]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 4.2, Avg: 4.5, Max: 4.7, Diff: 0.5, Sum: 17.9]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 2.5, Avg: 2.5, Max: 2.5, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 10.0]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 28, Avg: 39.0, Max: 53, Diff: 25, Sum: 156]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.4, Avg: 0.5, Max: 0.5, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 1.8]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 4.4, Avg: 4.6, Max: 4.8, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 18.4]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 4]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.4]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 12.1, Avg: 12.1, Max: 12.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 48.5]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 96537326.1, Avg: 96537326.2, Max: 96537326.2, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.3 ms]
   [Other: 3.6 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 1.4 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.1 ms]
   [Eden: 674.0M(674.0M)->0.0B(674.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->8192.0K Heap: 1428.6M(2048.0M)->755.3M(2048.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=2668 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 2097152K, used 773428K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000080104000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 8 young (8192K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 Metaspace       used 133822K, capacity 141304K, committed 141440K, reserved 1173504K
  class space    used 16174K, capacity 17421K, committed 17536K, reserved 1048576K
}
 [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
{Heap before GC invocations=2668 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 2097152K, used 1463604K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000080104000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 682 young (698368K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 Metaspace       used 133822K, capacity 141304K, committed 141440K, reserved 1173504K
  class space    used 16174K, capacity 17421K, committed 17536K, reserved 1048576K

2021-11-04T12:37:22.250+0800: 96601.445: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 45088768 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    3170160 bytes,    3170160 total
- age   2:    1426024 bytes,    4596184 total
- age   3:     396136 bytes,    4992320 total
- age   4:      67992 bytes,    5060312 total
- age   5:     123112 bytes,    5183424 total
- age   6:      64320 bytes,    5247744 total
- age   7:      75640 bytes,    5323384 total
- age   8:      56656 bytes,    5380040 total
- age   9:      87560 bytes,    5467600 total
- age  10:      79568 bytes,    5547168 total
- age  11:      34016 bytes,    5581184 total
- age  12:      47432 bytes,    5628616 total
- age  13:     115944 bytes,    5744560 total
- age  14:     133456 bytes,    5878016 total
- age  15:     477016 bytes,    6355032 total
, 0.1573301 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 12.2 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 96601587.8, Avg: 96601587.9, Max: 96601587.9, Diff: 0.1]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 4.0, Avg: 4.3, Max: 4.7, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 17.1]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 2.0, Avg: 2.1, Max: 2.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 8.3]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 30, Avg: 38.5, Max: 46, Diff: 16, Sum: 154]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.9, Avg: 0.9, Max: 1.0, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 3.6]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 4.3, Avg: 4.7, Max: 5.0, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 19.0]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 4]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 12.0, Avg: 12.1, Max: 12.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 48.3]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 96601599.9, Avg: 96601599.9, Max: 96601600.0, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.3 ms]
   [Other: 144.8 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 1.3 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.7 ms]
   [Eden: 674.0M(674.0M)->0.0B(674.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->8192.0K Heap: 1430.5M(2048.0M)->756.7M(2048.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=2670 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 2097152K, used 774853K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000080104000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 8 young (8192K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 Metaspace       used 133822K, capacity 141304K, committed 141440K, reserved 1173504K
  class space    used 16174K, capacity 17421K, committed 17536K, reserved 1048576K
}
 [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs] 
{Heap before GC invocations=2670 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 2097152K, used 1465029K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000080104000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 682 young (698368K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 Metaspace       used 133824K, capacity 141304K, committed 141440K, reserved 1173504K
  class space    used 16174K, capacity 17421K, committed 17536K, reserved 1048576K


2021-11-04T12:38:26.994+0800: 96666.190: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 45088768 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    3254096 bytes,    3254096 total
- age   2:    1682680 bytes,    4936776 total
- age   3:     837152 bytes,    5773928 total
- age   4:     280664 bytes,    6054592 total
- age   5:     204576 bytes,    6259168 total
- age   6:      41664 bytes,    6300832 total
- age   7:     114536 bytes,    6415368 total
- age   8:      64256 bytes,    6479624 total
- age   9:      68944 bytes,    6548568 total
- age  10:      39424 bytes,    6587992 total
- age  11:      73704 bytes,    6661696 total
- age  12:      66912 bytes,    6728608 total
- age  13:      33808 bytes,    6762416 total
- age  14:      47432 bytes,    6809848 total
- age  15:     115944 bytes,    6925792 total
, 0.0582912 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 11.2 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 96666233.8, Avg: 96666233.9, Max: 96666233.9, Diff: 0.1]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 3.2, Avg: 3.5, Max: 3.7, Diff: 0.5, Sum: 14.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 2.2, Avg: 2.3, Max: 2.5, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 9.0]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 10, Avg: 39.0, Max: 57, Diff: 47, Sum: 156]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.3, Avg: 0.6, Max: 0.7, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 2.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 4.5, Avg: 4.6, Max: 4.8, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 18.6]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 4]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.3]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 11.1, Avg: 11.1, Max: 11.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 44.4]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 96666245.0, Avg: 96666245.0, Max: 96666245.0, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.2 ms]
   [Other: 46.8 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 1.4 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.0 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.8 ms]
   [Eden: 674.0M(674.0M)->0.0B(673.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->9216.0K Heap: 1431.6M(2048.0M)->758.3M(2048.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=2672 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 2097152K, used 776487K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000080104000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 9 young (9216K), 9 survivors (9216K)
 Metaspace       used 133824K, capacity 141304K, committed 141440K, reserved 1173504K
  class space    used 16174K, capacity 17421K, committed 17536K, reserved 1048576K
}
 [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
{Heap before GC invocations=2672 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 2097152K, used 1465639K [0x0000000080000000, 0x0000000080104000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 682 young (698368K), 9 survivors (9216K)
 Metaspace       used 133824K, capacity 141304K, committed 141440K, reserved 1173504K
  class space    used 16174K, capacity 17421K, committed 17536K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: please show  more logs which surrounding with the first log( may be `grep -C 100 '2021-11-04T12:37:22.250+0800'` is enough.).

Comment: @pcloves More logs have been added.